# How to get an input word in the output? Beginning Java

Tags: java, string, output

I am trying to get the departure place in my out put but I am confused on how to do it. Do I have to declare it in the String method at the top?

```
    int seconds1;
    int seconds2;
    int minutes;
    int hours;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter departure city: ");
    String departure = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter arrival city ");
    String arrival = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter time (in seconds) it takes to travel between: ");
    seconds1 = sc.nextInt();

    hours = (seconds1 % 86400) / 3600;
    minutes = ((seconds1 % 86400) % 3600) / 60;
    seconds2 = ((seconds1 % 86400) % 3600) % 60;

    // I am trying to get this to say "The time between + departure + and + arrival+is"
    System.out.println("The time to travel  between and  is "); 

    System.out.println(hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds2);
  }
}
```

Comment: almost the same as you did on the next line for the time (hours, minutes,seconds2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have this:

```
System.out.println("The time to travel between " + departure + " and " + arrival + " is ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look-

```
package com.jap.falcon;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int seconds1;
        int seconds2;
        int minutes;
        int hours;

        System.out.println("Enter departure city: ");
        String departure = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter arrival city ");
        String arrival = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter time (in seconds) it takes to travel between: ");
        seconds1 = sc.nextInt();

        hours = (seconds1 % 86400) / 3600;
        minutes = ((seconds1 % 86400) % 3600) / 60;
        seconds2 = ((seconds1 % 86400) % 3600) % 60;

        System.out.println("The time to travel  between "+ departure +" and "+arrival+" is "); // I am trying to get this to say "The time between
                                                                    // + departure + and + arrival + is"
        System.out.println(hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `departure` and `arrival` variables in `System.out.println()` as shown in the below code:

```
System.out.println("The time to travel  between"+departure +" and"+arrival +"  is ");
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line:

```
   System.out.println("The time between " + departure + " and " + arrival + " is");
```

whole code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem2 {
public static void main( String [] args) {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int seconds1;
int seconds2;
  int minutes;
  int hours;

System.out.println("Enter departure city: ");
String departure = sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter arrival city ");
String arrival = sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter time (in seconds) it takes to travel between: ");
seconds1 = sc.nextInt();

hours = (seconds1 % 86400) / 3600;
minutes = ((seconds1 % 86400) % 3600) / 60;
seconds2 = ((seconds1 % 86400) % 3600) % 60;

     System.out.println("The time between " + departure + " and " + arrival + " is"); // I am trying to get this to say "The time between + departure + and + arrival + is"
System.out.println(hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds2);  


} }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is called concatenation.

As a baseline, concatenation is when you do the "addition" of Strings.

```
String a = "Hello, " + "World!";
System.out.println(a);            // Prints "Hello, World!"
```

This can also be done *within* the print statement.

```
System.out.println("Hello, " + "World!");
```

Since your departure location and destination are both already in the form of strings, it could look like this:

```
System.out.println("The time between " + departure + " and " + arrival + " is:");
```

To Java, your `departure` and `arrival` variables are already strings, so it will just insert them between your pre-typed strings. Don't forget to have spaces included in the strings (after "between", on either side of "and", and before "is". Hope this helps!